# Outlook is randomly deleting attachment(s) from mailitem during item send event

Tags: c#, email, outlook, outlook-redemption

I'm currently experiencing some strange behavior when sending e-mails using **Outlook (Office 365 Pro Plus)**.

Our software can generate e-mails and show a new mail compose to the user with attachments which they selected from our software. (We use both Redemption from our software as Outlook Object Model using an Outlook Add-in Express add-in)

Below you can find the code for generating the e-mail using Redemption:

```
            bool createEmail = false;
            RDOSession session = new RDOSession();
            session.Logon("", "", false, false, null, false);
            RDOFolder folder = session.GetDefaultFolder(rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderDrafts);
            RDOMail mail = folder.Items.Add("IPM.Note");

            ... Code for selecting receivers (returns string with emailadresses) ...
            ... Code for converting word documents to PDF / Adding the attachments to the mailitem ...

            RDOUserProperty userProp = mail.UserProperties.Add("DMS_AttachmentCount", rdoUserPropertyType.olInteger, false, false);
            userProp.Value = mail.Attachments.Count;

            mail.Display();
```

I noticed that I'm not using

> mail.Save();

Could that be the issue?

When we show the user the generated e-mail all attachments are in place and the user is able to open the attachments.

So far so good...

**Here comes the problem:**

> On sending the e-mail, sometimes (i mean really sometimes) some of the
> attachments are deleted from the e-mail. When the user goes to it's
> sent items and selects the e-mail, some of the attachments are
> deleted.

Since this occurs randomly, I'm not able to debug this issue.

What have I tried already:

> - Turn off ESET Nod32 and all of it's e-mail components
> - Disabled Office Secured Mode
> - Exclude certain file extensions from being scanned.
> - Checked for third party add-ins, so far only the list below is installed
>   [image]
>
>   The rest of the add-ins are default by Outlook

My question(s):

> - Is there somebody out there that has experienced the same problem?
> - How can I determine what happens inside the Item Send event?
> - What else can I turn off or apply on the server that might prevent this issue from happening?

Thanks.

Comment: are you sure its not exchange removing attachments for which it has been put in policy to do so?

Comment: @BugFinder It's not exchange since the customer is using Office 365.

Comment: is it specific file types that go, or just completely random, eg if you attached 20 texts, say 1 will go missing

Comment: It's completely random. I can attach 10 pdf's and 10 word documents, after sending 2 pdfs and 4 word documents "could be" deleted. or vice versa.

Comment: if you do the task manually, can you recreate the issue?

Comment: Unfortunatly no.....

Comment: What happens if you replace Send with Save? Are there any third party addins installed in Outlook?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I don't call the send event. The user sends the e-mail using Outlook Mail Compose window. I simply generate and show the e-mail with attachments from our software to the user.